# external api calls with env file

Tags: reactjs, api, environment-variables

Having an issue with calling an API key from my .env file.
if I use The key in the component it work.
However if I import it from the .env file it doesnt work.
Getting a 401 (Unauthorized).

> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

When i log the key from my component it work
I Tried many different ways to try to make it work but Can't figure it out,
I was looking for answers in a lot of places
I have seen this article published in the past but it didnt help:

*https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786*

my code:

```
import axios from "axios";

export async function fetchFoodSearch(searchFood) {

  const API_ID = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ID;
  const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;


  const fixSpaceStr = searchFood.replace(/\s+/g, "%20");

  const { data } = await axios.get(
    `https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/v2/parser?ingr=${fixSpaceStr}&app_id=${API_ID}&app_key=${API_KEY}`
  ,
    {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    }
  );

  return data;
}
```

my .env file:

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY = "somthing";
REACT_APP_API_ID = "somthing";
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Are you able to get or console the value of keys in the code (fetchFoodSearch function) from env file?

Comment: Have you console log API_ID and API_KEY in the component? Make sure to add require('dotenv').config(); in the top of component.

Comment: yes i console log the value from the .env file

Comment: CORS should be controlled on your backend server. Please check CORS setting on your API.

Answer (score 0):

The cors error don't related to the ENV file.

Try to add `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json}` to your axios call.

Comment: I tried it, it didnt work